# Shunt current measurement on phase

Tags: current, motor-controller, shunt

I measure the current of two phases (directly phase current, not the low side MOSFET current) of a PMSM motor and on some hardwares (2 of 10) I have issues with the phase current measurements.

As a current measurement IC I use the INA240:
(https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina240-q1.pdf)

Two 1mOhm shunts are used with 1% accuracy, so this should not be the problem. Also a Kelvin connetion is etablished, so the error there should be really low.

Here are some plots of phase A and B (I turned by hand at 10A, 100mV/A) and you can see, that phase B has around 10% too much current applied:

Phase A:

[image]

Phase B:

[image]

So my questions is, what can cause such a problem? The error is linear in current and around 10% and only 2 of 10 boards have this on one phase, where this one depicted here is the worst. Can this occur through bad soldering? I also have vias in the shunt pads, this was maybe a bad idea, but I cannot see any solder pulled away and I also added more solder, but I cannot see any difference.

Here is a picture of the shunts layout on the PCB:
[image]

**Edit:** The reference current Iq is 10A and the two traces show phase A and phase B when I turn the motor slowly by hand. You can see, that phase B applies around 11A, but it measures 10A through the shunt.

**Edit2:** What I see is, that the footprint is too large and not as intended in the datasheet. So this might cause the problem, when solder creeps up to the resistor. The resistor itself is this one:CSS2H-2512R-1L00FE and the solder can potentially stick at the surface and change the resistance. But I'm not 100% sure yet, since I cannot see the bottom side of it

Comment: Are the 8 individuals that work correctly *exactly* accurate or are the errors distributed, where 20% are simply part of that (normal) distribution? The vias are no problem, there is no current on those tracks (assuming they lead to the INA240).

Comment: Do those scope images show the shunt voltage directly? Btw, the images have low resolution and I can barely decipher the essentisl detsils...

Comment: Hi, the 8 other work more or less exactly, i mean the vias on the shunt pads, they might pull away solder and so maybe a bad solder connection could cause this?

Comment: I will post better screenshots soon

Comment: I just see two traces A and B, and there is no reference trace from a scope current probe and its type.  " and you can see, that phase B has around 10% too much current applied", with respect to which reference? Did you connect both A and B shunts in series, so it is showing the same current? I don't fully understand what those traces represent, please edit and make it more clear.

Comment: I edited this info. The reference is a Iq of 10A, where Ib seems to measure 10A, but applies 11A. The two signals come from phase current measurement when I turn the motor by hand at 10A Iq

Comment: do you have filter components on the shunt signal tracks to the INA? these can add a lot of error due to unbalance

Comment: Hi, no there is no filter on the INA input to the shunt, the tracks are next to each other and have GND guards. A Filter is at the output of the INA240 with a cut off frequency of 40kHz

Comment: This is an XY problem. You claim error in INA240 measurement, without comparing a reading with an instrument. Moreover the scope trace shows negative values, while the INA240 can only output positive value, so where do you measure this voltage? Then you talk about set Iq and some mismatch, like saying: I have set a temperature to 100 degrees on my PID controller, but the reading (not specified which) shows 110, do I have a faulty temperature sensor?